# DirectAdmin web hosting error "Warning: file_exists(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/autoload.php) is not within the allowed path(s):"

Tags: laravel, vue.js, cpanel, web-hosting, directadmin

I am trying to host a website(Laravel + Vue) via DirectAdmin but the site shows error.
[image]

I don't know how to fix it.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The PHP script is trying to access the folder for which access is not allowed. This restriction is defined by the PHP open_basedir variable for each domain separately.

To turn off open_basedir on DirectAdmin, you need to possess administrative level privileges.

Go to the Extra Features section
Under PHP SafeMode Configuration > select Php Safe Mode Settings. Here, you have the option to either enable or disable open_basedir for your domains.

The .htaccess file can be used to configure specific settings for your website that can be applied on a per-directory basis.

By using the "php_admin_value open_basedir" directive in the .htaccess file, you can override the default open_basedir setting defined in the server's PHP configuration and limit the access of PHP scripts to specific directories. For example:

```
php_admin_value open_basedir "/home/example/public_html/"
```